# Do multiple instances of a single Azure Web App share a single disk?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm developing an app in in Azure Web Apps (formerly Websites) and want to be sure I understand how the local disk is used in a multiple instance scenario. When I scale to multiple instances, do they share a single virtual disk with all of the app files?

Consider this example:

- An app running on 5 instances
- A page in the app that uploads a file to the local disk, say  to Server.MapPath("~/Content") (I know Storage would be better, but just for concept)
- Will all 5 instances have access to this file, or will it only exist on the instance where it was uploaded?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, all your instances will be sharing the same **persistent** state, which includes everything under `d:\home` (your site bits are in `d:\home\site\wwwroot`).

There is also temp space under `d:\local` which is **not** shared, but this won't hurt your scenario.

See [this](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-runtime-environment#file-system) for more detail on this topic.

Comment: David, where would you put a SQLite db file? `D:\home\data\db.sqlite`, `D:\home\site\db.sqlite`, `D:\home\site\wwwroot\db.sqlite`, somewhere else? I guess, `\wwwroot\db.sqlite` might be removed during deployment by Kudu with default settings, right?

Comment: @David - Today I have a single-instance website that uses NLog to write to a log file on d:\home\logfiles\.  If my site scales out, each instance is going to clobber the others' log files, correct?

Comment: That depends. Conceivably, they could all do line appends to the same file. Or you may need to vary the filename for each instance.